# Why are the dynamic options appearing so small?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have a drop-down menu that I am dynamically adding options to (based on an AJAX call) on an `onfocus` event. For some reason, the first time I click on the box, the options appear condensed into a tiny box, but the second time it works just fine. Does anyone know what might be causing this phenomenon? (Note: Because it involves AJAX, I can't insert a fiddle that could simulate the error, but I will post the code itself)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Remove Class | IMS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/form.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label for="class">Class:</label>
            <select name="class" onfocus="loadClasses(this)" id="drop" required>
                <option>Sample Value</option>
            </select>
            <hr/>
            <button type="button" onclick="sendData()">Remove Class</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
function genDrop(e, json) {
    e.innerHTML = "";
    var data = eval("({data: " + json + "})");
    data = data.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var option = data[i];
        var o = document.createElement("option");
        o.value = option.id;
        o.innerHTML = option.name;
        o.setAttribute("descript", option.descript);
        o.style.width = "500px !important"
        o.style.maxWidth = "200%";
        e.appendChild(o);
    }
}

function loadClasses(e) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
            genDrop(e, http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.open("GET", "getclasses.php", true);
    http.send();
}
```

Comment: My guess would be the browser sees only one option when you first open it, and doesn't recalculate when you add the new options. I'd suggest loading the options in when the page loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onload instead of onfocus

```
<select name="class" onload="loadClasses(this)" id="drop" required>
  <option>Sample Value</option>
</select>
```